# doesn't exist an $N$ s.t. all $n \ge N$ satisfy an equation.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I came across this problem on my own and i'm asking for any potential techniques/strategies/hints for attacking it.

> Prove that there does not exist an $N$ such that for every natural
>   number $n \ge N$; 
>          $n = {cx \pm 1\over 6}$ for some odd $c \ge 3$, for some odd $x \ge 5$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify...you want this to hold for one or the other sign or do you need it for both?

Comment: @lulu Either plus or minus, not necessarily both

Comment: So...for example, this is false for every $n$ in between two odd primes.  So if we knew the there were infinitely many Twin Primes, we'd be done.  (not that this solves your problem, just an observation).

Answer (score 4):

I believe this problem is equivalent to the Twin Primes conjecture (TPC)

To see that TPC implies your question:  Suppose we had such an $N$.  Choose Twin primes larger than $6N$.  Then we have the triple $\{m-1,m,m+1\}$ where $m\pm 1$ are both prime.  Clearly $6$ divides $m$ and $n=\frac m6$ is a counterexample.

To see that your question implies the TPC...suppose the TPC is false.  Then choose $N$ so big that there are no Twin Primes greater than $N$.  Then for $n≥N$ we know that at least one of $6n\pm 1$ is composite and thus we can find $c,x$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I have shown that it is. Was just wondering if there was any ways to attack the problem from this angle.

Comment: I'd say the problems were almost literally equivalent, so I doubt that it helps. But you never know!

Comment: haha, it's a good way to waste my time anyway